# C# How to list an object value

Tags: c#, object

I have a function that needs `Object` class to run.

```
double[] arraySegment = new double[window];
Object array = new Object();
array = arraySegment;
Object entropyResult = ent.entropy(array);
```

When I put a break point to last line, it shows me a result like this:

[image]

I need to list the value "2.0168..." inside of it. How can i reach it?

Comment: just cast it to double

Comment: Why cast a perfectly good typed double[] into an Object in the first place?

Comment: Because `entropy` function has no overload to take double[].

Comment: Is it not a class that you have control over? Can you not modify it to accept a new overload?

Comment: If it accepts Object, it accepts anything. Double[] inherits from Object like all other C# classes.

Comment: Ok. I just changed that line `var entropyResult = ent.entropy(array);' You are right sorry. No need to cast it as an object. Also `Double value = ((Double[,])entropyResult)[0,0]` is what i need. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object entropyResult = ent.entropy(array);
Double value = ((Double[,])entropyResult)[0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the following work?

```
Console.WriteLine( ((double[,])ent.entropy(array))[0,0] );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it back as an array then you can access it by index

```
double[] newArray = array as double[];

if(newArray != null) 
{
double val = newArray[0,0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing anything more about the function `entropy`, this is my best guess:

```
double[] arraySegment = new double[window];
Object array = new Object();
array = arraySegment;
Object entropyResult = ent.entropy(array);
double[,] result = (double[,]) entropyResult;
double resultValue = result[0,0];
```

You need to cast the `Object` result to something that you can access the indexed double from.